# How to conditionally find top parent element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have HTML structure like below, what I need to do is find the child span element with innerHTML a's most top parent element until it's class name is not "here", so for this example, the target element is where the comment located.

```
<span class="here">
     <span> <!-- This is the parent -->
        <span>
        <span>
          <span>a</span>
          <span>b</span>   
        </span>
        </span>
     <span>
</span>
```

Comment: How are you selecting the `<span>`?

Comment: From what element are you starting?

Comment: Why so many spans? Is this the actual layout or just an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.closest` with a while loop, something like `while node.class != here -> node.closest`. Or `.closest('.here')` Or just use `node.firstElementChild`

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.here')

const target = parent.firstElementChild

console.log(target.innerHTML)

/*

 <!-- This is the parent -->
        <span>
        <span>
          <span>a</span>
          <span>b</span>   
        </span>
        </span>
*/
```

It's unclear what exactly you're doing / why you're doing it so I can't tell you which solution would be best or if any of these is the right solution here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score -3):

You can use closest; check the link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: While this answer is essentially correct, it’s inadequate in that it doesn’t explain how `closest()` can be used.